# Can we program and debug STM32F401C via SWD interface using STM32 Cube IDE and STM32CubeMX?

Tags: stm32, embedded, programming, stm32cubemx

I am planning to use STM32F401C microcontroller for my project, so I am in the process of gaining knowledge on it.

I am planning to use the SWD interface to program as well as debug the microcontroller using STlink-V2.

I know I am able to program the target microcontroller using below software:

1. IAR Embedded Workbench
2. ARM Keil
3. STM32 Cube programmer

**My doubt is: Can we program and debug (using ST link v2) via SWD interface using STM32 Cube IDE, by creating embedded C and C++ code and generating the program using STM32 CubeMX?**

https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html

Comment: what else would that IDE be for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CubeIDE with integrated CubeMX configuration tool to write software, compile, build, program and debug, by using ST-LINK/V2 interface and using both SWD and JTAG protocols.